# How to do element-wise comparison between two NumPy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays. I would like to do an element-wise comparison between the two of them to find out which values are the same.

```
a= np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b= np.array([[3,2],[1,4]])
```

Is there a way for me to compare these two arrays to 1) find out which values are the same and 2) get the index of the same values?

Adding on to the previous question, is there a way for me to return 1 if the values are the same and 0 otherwise?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: numpy supports comparison operator `a==b`

Comment: As well as `np.where(a==b)` for indices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
a= np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b= np.array([[3,2],[1,4]])

#1) find out which values are the same
a==b
# array([[False,  True],
#        [False,  True]])

#2) get the index of the same values?
np.where((a==b) == True) # or np.where(a==b)
#(array([0, 1]), array([1, 1]))

# Adding on to the previous question, is there a way for me to return 1 if the values are the same and 0 otherwise
(a==b).astype(int)
# array([[0, 1],
#        [0, 1]])
```